# Trouble connecting NXT 2.0 block to Mindstorms Home EV3 software on Mac

Tags: ev3, nxt, bluetooth, mac

My son has finally shown an interest in Mindstorms and we are trying to use an NXT block with my 2015 Macbook Pro (latest OS) running the EV3 Mindstorms home edition software.

I have read in many posts and Youtube videos that it is possible to program in the EV3 software and upload to the NXT 2.0 brick - with a few caveats for updated sensors not being included and etc.

However my problem is I just cant see to connect the NXT by either Bluetooth or USB using the 'connect' icon at the top left of the program window. The NXT is connected Bluetooth as shows in the connected devices list. The Wizard goes through the steps to connect but just wont find it under Bluetooth or USB and just sits there.

When I try and connect in reverse from the NXT block itself to my Mac - it can then see Mac but when I click on it - it says 'failed!' on the NXT LCD.

The NXT version is showing as 1.31

The software I downloaded is 'Mindstorms home' 1.5.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The "new" Scratch-based LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 software products don't support NXT. This includes "MINDSTORMS Home" and "EV3 Classroom".

The "old" LabView-based EV3 software does support NXT. However, it is 32-bit software and won't run on modern macOS because they require 64-bit software.

If you have access to a Windows computer or can run a Windows VM on your Mac, you can use the "old" EV3 software or even the original NXT software. Both are still available for download on the LEGO Education [Retired Products](https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/retiredproducts/) page.

Comment: this makes sense now - thanks very much for the response